# Check if number belongs to a series

Tags: algorithms, modular-arithmetic

I have two series

$0,3,4,7,8,11,12,\ldots$

$1,2,5,6,9,10,13,14,\ldots$

If I give a number to a function it should return whether the number belongs to first series on second series

For ex:

3 - First Series
13 - Second Series

So what is simple and fast.

Comment: modulo $4$ would fit

Comment: @Henry how? 0 mod 4 is 0,1 mod 4 is 1. How it solves my prob

Comment: @Madhan The number in the first series are $0$ and $3$ mod $4$ and in the other are $1$ and $2$ mod $4$.

Comment: @SahibaArora Thanks your explanation helped me.

Comment: @Henry If you could add that as an answer with Sahiba's explanation I will accept that as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*As requested in comments and combining my and Sahiba Arora's comments:*

If you take the integers modulo $4$, i.e. the remainder on division by $4$, then

- those in the first sequence are equivalent to $0$ or $3$ mod $4$
- those in the second sequence are equivalent to $1$ or $2$ mod $4$